# mongoose get all related object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
let Schema = mongoose.Schema

let simpleSchema = new Schema({
    company: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company', require: true }
    ....
})
```

and this schema has not `anotherSchema` reference. but that `anotherSchema` has `simpleSchema` reference

```
let anotherSchema = new Schema({
    simple: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Simple', require: true }
    ....
})
```

so when I create model from first schema

```
return mongoose.model('Simple', simpleSchema)
```

and I call this:

```
simpleSchema.statics.testpopulate = function (id) {
return this.findOne()
  .where('_id').equals(id)
  .populate('company')
  .populate('simple')
  .then((s) => {
    console.log('sc', s.company)
    console.log('sp', s.simple)
    return Promise.resolve(s)
  }).catch((err) => {
    return Promise.reject(err)
  })
}
```

It only logs company. I know that it's right but how can I force to return simple as well?

So I want to retrieve all object which has reference to my simple collection as well